# Notepad++ tab color by file type

Tags: plugins, notepad++

Is there any extension of notepad++ allows me to set the tab color by file type (xml/javascript/php)?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

That's a very nice idea. Currently there are no plugins that make it possible.

Why don't you post a [feature request](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Afeature) for that?